# Reading "keydown" inputs separated by space

Tags: rxjs

I want to display tokens (words) by joining the keys the user enters until she hits space or enter. It seems trivial in JS but in rxJs I have been trying lots of ways and got stuck!

Start with this please:

```
const source = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(someDiv, 'keydown')
//.YOUR_SOL
.subscribe(w=>{console.log(w)})
```

For example:
'a','b','c',SPACE,'a','b' => "abc", "ab"

Many thanks!

Comment: Can you give an example of an input and the expected behavior?
If the user hit 'a', 'b', 'c', SPACE, 'a', 'b' what is the expected output?

Comment: 'a', 'b', 'c', SPACE, 'a', 'b' => abc, ab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
const keyDown$ = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(document, 'keydown').pluck('key');

const isSpaceOrEnter = x => [' ', 'Enter'].includes(x);

const spaceOrEnter$ = keyDown$.filter(isSpaceOrEnter);

keyDown$
  .filter(x => !isSpaceOrEnter(x))
  .buffer(spaceOrEnter$)  
  .map(x => x.join(""))
  .subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

You can test it here: https://jsfiddle.net/abwtf2xu/1/

Comment: Perfect! Thanks! Now if I need to react to every key pressed. After .filter(x => !isSpaceOrEnter(x)) I have the current char that is not space or enter.